# Replacing all values in a table > $T$

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to generate a table of Euclidean distances from the points in a list to a given point, e.g.:

```
Table[EuclideanDistance[MyList[[i]], c], {i, 1, Length[MyList]}]
```

Moreover, when `EuclideanDistance` returns a value greater than $T$, I'd like to replace that value with a given real number $R$. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use `Clip`?

```
MyList = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
c = {0, 0};
t = 1;
r = -1;

Clip[
 Table[EuclideanDistance[MyList[[i]], c], {i, 1, Length[MyList]}],
 {0, 1}, {0, r}]

(* ==>  {0.9957995322104205`,0.3452581732209688`,0.016464628727136405`,
  -1,-1,0.5914902487316964`,0.8531216593853862`,-1,0.9996775567985703`,
  -1} *)
```

Here, `r = -1` is the value that replaces any number above the threshold `t = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on Jens method that does the calculation by mapping the function `EuclideanDistance` onto the list and then clipping the result:

```
myList = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
c = {0, 0}; t = 1; r = -1;
Clip[EuclideanDistance[#, c] & /@ myList, {0, 1}, {0, r}]
```